# C# Expression List contains

Tags: .net, linq, expression

I am sorry about the description. My English is not good. Let me try to describe it again.

Say I have the LamdaExpression as the parameter for a method which named FindProducts. Now I need to parse this parameter in the FindProducts method, now the issue I encountered is that I could not get the value from the list of this parameter when parameter is like below code(Listn.Contains()):

```
var sFilter = new List<string>(){"AFilter", "BFilter"};
myObj.FindProducts(s => sFilter.Contains(s.Name)); --- Here the parameter is an expression
```

My questions is how do I get the values in the list sFilter(AFilter and BFilter) in method FindProducts?

All I want to do is that parse this Expression, then convert it to as SQL script. In my case, I want to do is like this: FindProducts(s=>filterList.Constains(s)), here I would try to parse the S as the column name, filterList should be in clause in SQL. Finally I would make my SQL like this: select * from TABLE where S in ('A', 'B') which is from that expression

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about what you're trying to do here? I've read the question a few times and can't make sense of it.

Comment: For me it's totally unclear what you are trying to achieve here. If this comments get's upvoted, consider rephrasing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. I just init the List in the expression. Then I parse it as ListInitExpression and get the value. The code like below:

```
myObj.FindProducts(s => new List<string>() { "AFilter", "BFilter" }.Contains(s.Name) && s.FactoryID==4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if I am interpreting your question correctly):

```
var productList = new List<string>() {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
var filterList  = new List<string>() {"A", "B"}; 

var foundList = FindProducts(productList, s => filterList.Contains(s));

List<string> FindProducts(List<string> products, Func<string,bool> filter) {
    return products.Where(s => filter(s)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This is not working for my case. The FindProducts can only accept one parameter which is an Expression. And in the FindProducts method, I have to parse this Expression, then convert it to as SQL script. In my case, I want to do is like this: FindProducts(s=>filterList.Constains(s)), here the I would try to parse the S as the column name, filterList should be in clause in SQL. Finally I would make my SQL like this: select * from TABLE where S in ('A', 'B')

Comment: Then make `productList` a field or property instead of a local variable.

Comment: But how do I set the value to this field or property in the expression?

Comment: Finally I figured it out. I just init the List in the expression. Then I parse it as ListInitExpression and get the value